# Trying to figure out how to use < in a command

Tags: command-line, bash, docker, pipe

I've been learning docker which has led me to create a container with ubuntu. I am also kinda new to linux commands in general and was trying to get a better understanding of redirection.

I used > to send outputs of commands to files like so

```
ls -l > dir_contents.txt
```

I also used | to process ls -l so I can get just the file name like so

```
head -n 1 ~/etc_content.txt | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Now what I want to do is send the previous command to cat so I can list the contents of the file. What I am currently doing is

```
cat < head -n 1 ~/etc_content.txt | awk '{print $NF}'
```

This tells me there is no file or directory after running that command. I think that means it worked but my path is messed up somehow?

The data I am directly working with is the filename adduser.conf in the directory /etc. So I am not certain what the problem may be.

Edit: Grammar fix

Comment: You want [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) `$( ... )`, not redirection, here. `cat "$(head -n 1 ~/etc_content.txt | awk '{print $NF}')"`.

Comment: Note also that [redirecting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) is different from [piping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines).

Comment: Okay, sweet. I just ran that command and it totally worked! Thanks for the help